multiple subdomains from single nextjs website
I've got multiple subdomains being served by a single nextjs application. I need to implement a unique gtm tag for each subdomain.
The problem seems to be that when a page is generated, the server/nextjs has no idea which subdomain it will wind up on, so it can't assign the correct tag.
My approach was to load all the tags when the page is generated on the server, and when the page is rendered by a client it assigns the right one. But it's not working.
Does anyone have any better ideas?
